# ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR ON Exporting more than 500 in csv from database

Tags: php

I am getting `ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` on exporting more than 500 row in csv from database

Increase max_execution_time up to 240 in php.ini and on the page also, then also error

```
if(isset($_POST['export1']) || !empty($_POST['$row[id]']))
{ 

 $filename ="excelreport.xls";
 include('include/conectdb.php');

$q3 = "SELECT * FROM response"; 
//echo $q1;
$r3= mysqli_query($dbc,$q3);
if(mysqli_num_rows($r3)>0)
{
    $_SESSION['export1']='';
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r3))

    {
        if(isset($_POST[$row1['id']])=='$row1[id]')
        {
            if(!empty($row1['id']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['export1']=$_SESSION['export1'].$row1['id'].',';

                }
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['export1']=rtrim($_SESSION['export1'],',');   
    //echo $_SESSION['export'];
}
//$contents = "Username \t Campaign \t Name \t Email \t Contact \t Gender \t Address \t Date \t Status\n";
    $contents = "Name \t Email \t Contact \t Gender \t Address \t Query \t Date \t Status\n";
    $export_id = explode(',',$_SESSION['export1']); 
    for($i=0;$i<count($export_id);$i++)
        {
            //echo $export_id[$i];
            $q4 = "SELECT * FROM response where id = $export_id[$i]"; 
            //echo $q1;
            $r4= mysqli_query($dbc,$q4);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($r4)>0)
            {
              while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r4))

                    {



                    }

           }
           else
           echo '';

       }

        header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0"); 
        echo $contents;
        exit();

}
```

Comment: Check your error logs, what is the actual error that's causing the 500?

Comment: or turn on error displaying, it's most likely hitting the memory limit.